# RxJS conceptual help: access and refresh tokens, non-simultaneous refresh

Tags: jwt, rxjs6

I'm new to RxJS and am asking for conceptual help on how to approach the following process:

1. Backend is secured with short lived JWT access tokens. Upon authentication, client is issued initial access token and long lived refresh token. Refresh token can be used to create a new access token.
2. The client can decode the tokens and *knows* if a token is expired or not. The client shall refresh access tokens lazily when they are expired; not retry a a failing request.
3. The client shall not issue multiple refresh-requests simultaneously.

The last part I struggle with. I imagine a semaphore, or "gate" of some kind:

- The first refresh-request passes through the gate and locks it behind itself. It then initiates the actual token-refresh.
- Other refresh-requests are blocked at the gate, waiting to pass.
- The completion of the token-refresh stores the new access token and lifts the gate.
- All refresh-requests return the new access token.

I found [this code](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/15#issuecomment-377681482) that uses redux to implement the gate. Is that necessary?

Alternatively, could the gate be implemented by a `BehaviorSubject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution! The code is available [here](https://github.com/skalio/token-refresh-demo).

The gate *is* using a `BehaviorSubject` to have a singleton holding the state. By applying a filter I get a blocking gate that will allow passage when the underlying gate is lifted:

```
const gate$ = new BehaviorSubject(true); // open at first
const openGate$ = gate$.pipe(
    filter(x => x === true),
    take(1)   // take only one event, then complete
);

// wait for the gate to open
openGate$.subscribe(() => {
    // do something
});

// close the gate:
gate$.next(false);

// and open it again
gate$.next(true);
```

By using a `BehaviourSubject`, the gate is initialised and open by default.